# Is there a limit to simultaneous Mongo inserts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of Codes that I am populating from a CSV. There are a total of 1.5M codes, quite a few. The CSV is readily parsed into an object or the form:

```
codes = [
  {code:'abc'},
  {code:'123'},
  etc
]
```

I initially tried writing this to Mongo in one insert, like so

```
Code.collection.insert(codes)
```

(using Mongoose to compose the query directly).

However this failed silently. Assuming some kind of hidden memory issue I began chunking my code, and found that Mongo 2.6 (running locally on my 16Gb Macbook, no replica sets) would accept around 1000 codes in a single insert.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so, is there any rationale to this number?

Comment: does [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) help

Comment: Good RTFM, but it doesn't match. The  quoted limit is 250k records

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting using the **[Bulk Operation Methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/)**, in particular you would need the **[`db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp)** method which can be exposed within Mongoose using the `Model.collection` accessor object. Thus, in the above you could restructure your inserts to do a bulk update as follows:

```
var bulk = Code.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

codes.forEach( function(obj) ) {
    bulk.find({'code': {'$ne': null}}/* some search */)
        .update({'$set': {'code': obj.code}});
    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err, result) {             
            bulk = Code.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        });
    }
}

if (counter % 1000 != 0 ) {
    bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
       // get stats
    });
}
```